# How to make Laravel Collection of Object instead of Array

Tags: laravel, collections, laravel-collection

How to make Laravel Collection of Object instead of Array ?

If I do like this :

```
$result = collect([
    'foo' => [
        'success' => 0,
        'failed' => 0
    ],
    'bar' => [
        'success' => 0,
        'failed' => 0
    ]
]);
```

I will get new instance of laravel collection of array. But, How to make collection of object instead of array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This:

```
$result = json_decode(
    collect([
        'foo' => [
            'success' => 0,
            'failed' => 0
        ],
        'bar' => [
            'success' => 0,
            'failed' => 0
        ]
    ])->toJson()
);
```