# Laravel collection of object results in associative array instead of object?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon, laravel-collection

When I wrap a regular object into a collection, the result is an associative array.

I would like to keep using it as an object.

```
$obj = (object) ['count'=>1, 'now'=>Carbon::now()];
dump($obj); // $obj->count = 1, $obj->now = Carbon {...}

$collection = collect($obj);
dump($collection); // unwanted: $collection['count'] = 1, $collection['now'] = Carbon {...}
```

In a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61119152/how-to-make-laravel-collection-of-object-instead-of-array) the offered solution is to `json_encode`/`json_decode` the `$collection`.
But that modifies the object and loses information (e.g. converts the `now` Carbon object to a string).

```
$collection = json_decode(collect($obj)->toJson());
dump($collection); // unwanted: $collection->count = 1, $collection->now = "2021-05-25T10:43:34.301505Z"
```

How can I wrap an object into a collection without turning it into an associative array?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that's because a collection is considered an array of multiple entries. Technically, you're passing just one unwrapped entry whose properties are considered array entries for the collection. So I'd say, you're using the collection wrong.

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-contains):

> The Illuminate\Support\Collection class provides a fluent, convenient wrapper for working with **arrays** of data.

Another way of emphasizing this, is that the `Collection` class implements the [`ArrayAccess`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface. Therefore, this is what happens: When creating a `Collection` via `collect()`, the passed data is set to `$this->items`. So `Collection` is not an array, it just lets you access the contents of `$this->items` via array notation.

Comment: And to answer "How can I wrap an object into a collection without turning it into an associative array?" you need to `collect([ $obj ])`.

Comment: That's possible but it still won't let them do `$obj->count`. Accessing it via array notation (`$obj[0]->count`) remains

Comment: It could very well be that I'm using the collection wrong. But, similar situation when using array of objects `collect([$obj1, $obj2])`. Would like collection helpers to chain e.g. filter / except / ... . E.g. for the collection return the objects, except its `now` property and then group them by count. This works fine for Laravel models but not for simple objects?

Comment: It's a bit vague to answer that. Isn't that a whole new question?